# e possível passar string da classe string como ponteiro para função?

Tags: c++, string, ponteiro

e possível passar string da classe string como ponteiro para função?

exemplo:

```
void separaStr(string *modulo, satring *nmodulo, *digito){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumo que estejas a perguntar se é possivel passar para uma função, um apontador para uma std::string.

Sim, é possível. A assinatura da função seria, por exemplo:

```
int funcao(std::string *str)
```

No entanto e por norma, sugeria que, sempre que o argumento da função seja necessário (não possa ser `null`) e caso a função não guarde um apontador ou de qualquer outra forma altere a propriedade/posse (ownership) do argumento, substituisses o uso de um apontador pelo uso de uma referência.

O uso da referência permite, tal como com o apontador, alterar o valor da string e em termos de sintaxe a diferença no uso do parâmetro seria

```
str.membro (str é uma referência)
```

ao invés de

```
str->membro (str é um apontador)
```

Um dos beneficios do uso de uma referência é o facto de que a referência claramente expressa a condição de que o parâmetro da função não pode ser nulo.

Num projecto de maior dimensão isto poderá por exemplo, ajudar a facilmente identificar pontos no código onde é necessário verificar se o argumento é nulo e os casos onde efectuar esta validação é desnecessária.

A assinatura da função que recebe uma string passada por referência seria:

```
int funcao(std::string &str)
```

ou

```
int funcao(const std::string &str)
```

para os casos em que o parâmetro não seja alterado na função.

**Uma máxima que tento seguir sempre que programo em C++ é:**

- Utiliza uma referência sempre que possível e um apontador apenas onde estritamente necessário.

Comment: muito obrigado, eu estive espanando 1bit por um '&'.